# How to change the facebook embed posts data-href value on button click

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have used facebook embed post tag in my webpage using the following code.

```html
<body>
  <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2">.</script>  
 <div class="fb-post" id="postdata"
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/"
      data-width="500"></div>
</body>
```

Here I would like to change the data-href url dynamically on button click. I have added the code in java script as following

document.getElementById('postdata').setAttribute('data-href', 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1708237652618894&set=a.273653222744018&type=3&theater')

The change on button click is not happening. The default post only coming up.

how can I change it.

Comment: The JS SDK goes through your document looking for such elements only once on initialization. If you need it to parse new or modified elements later on, you need to call `FB.XFBML.parse()`.

Comment: (It might not work if you just change the `data-href` attribute; the SDK adds additional data/classes to those elments to mark them as already parsed. When in doubt, replace the complete element with a new one first (for example via `.outerHTML='…'`), and then call the mentioned method.)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. It is working fine you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as @CBroe mentioned.
In main.js

FB.init({
        appId: '{YOUR APP ID}',
        status: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.7'
    });

< -- Assign value to the data-href-->

FB.XFBML.parse()

It will render the current url changes